# node.js complaining that "The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH" even though chromedriver is on the path

Tags: linux, node.js, path, selenium-chromedriver

I’m using node 5.10.0 on Linux.  Having some issues running my script, which are displayed below

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ node SkyNet.js 
Validation Complete
/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:185
      throw Error(
      ^

Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and   ensure it can be found on your PATH.
    at Error (native)
    at new ServiceBuilder (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:185:13)
    at getDefaultService (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:362:22)
    at Driver (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:771:34)
    at Builder.build (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:464:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/davea/mydir/js/Optimus.js:14:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
```

It is saying chromedriver isn’t on my path, but I just downloaded the appropriate version from here — http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/ , and as you can see, it is on my PATH

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/davea/bin:/home/davea/bin:/usr/lib/chromedriver
```

with the following permissions …

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ ls -al /usr/lib/chromedriver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 davea evotext 5503600 Feb  3  2014 /usr/lib/chromedriver
```

So I am confused as to why I’m getting this error.  Any help is appreciated, - Dave

Answer (score 48):

To add to Niels' answer, for those not using Babel

1. First install the chromedrive package using npm. If you install globally ensure to have node packages in your path

> ```
> npm install -g chromedriver
> ```

If PATH errors persist, just save it to the local project's dependencies

```
npm install --save-dev chromedriver
```

2. For those not using Babel

> ```
> const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
> const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
> const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
>
> chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());
> ```

Comment: This works and thanks. Those should be `const` and not `let`. Also, you might want to include the instantiation of the usable driver after you've made the setting happen.

Comment: Yep, downloading the driver and providing the $PATH is not sufficient. I had to use npm install -g chromedriver

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue. I have resolved it by taking the path from chromedriver package.

Here is my code:

```
import webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';
import chrome from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';
import chromedriver from 'chromedriver';

chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
                 .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
                 .build();
```

Which is based on the code from this answer: [Passing require('chromedriver).path directly to selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733731/passing-requirechromedriver-path-directly-to-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: This is great, but it requires knowledge of babel and transpiling. I just want to point out that all the `import varariableName from 'package-name'` could be: `const variableName = require('package-name');` in the simplest form.

Answer (score 10):

Might be a little late but if someone comes across this problem for me worked the following:

First `npm install -g chromedriver --save`

Then add this line on top of your code `require('chromedriver');`

Here is a demo:

```
require('chromedriver');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build();
driver.get('https://google.com');
```

For more details you can go here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver

Comment: What do you mean add this at the top of our code?  I don't have any code, I have a .side file.  Where does this code go?

Comment: It's using nodejs so it'll need to be a js file. Add to the top of your e2e test e.g. `VisitGoogle.js`. `driver.get('https://google.com');` is an example of telling chrome driver to visit google.com. For more details you'll need to read the docs

Comment: You are saving chromedrive globally and to the package dependencies. This will both save chromedrive globally and also to `node_modules`. npm resolution will look in `node_modules` first, hence global install is not needed. This is double handling and confusing. You should either (1) save globally `-g` and add to `peerDependencies`; or (2) save to dependencies `-s` or `--save`

Answer (score 4):

Just Download the driver .exe file into the same folder as your current project file is lying. It worked for me. Might work for you as well.
Peace!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

for my small `selenium-webdriver` test i did these steps after i researched online and here:

1. `npm install selenium-webdriver`
2. `npm install chromedriver`
3. `npm install geckodriver` and opened file library.js and `npm init` and ran `node library.js` **(source code below)**
4. `Error:` `(node:14212) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id` Some long error related to not same chromedriver version. so i checked the chrome browser version manually in the browser. it was `version 73` and my mistake i had downloaded `chromedriver version 74.0`.
5. so go to `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=73.0.3683.68/` download according to your OS and download it in `~/Downloads` .
6. then in open `terminal` in the `~/Downloads` folder.
7. then `USER@DESKTOP:~/Downloads$ unzip ~/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/Downloads` You will get the raw `chromedriver` file in `~/Downloads` folder.
8. now i moved the `ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68` file to two places - `usr/local/bin` and `usr/bin` in my system.
9. there was already a `chromedriver` file in `usr/local/bin` .
10. to move the file - `USER@DESKTOP:~/Downloads$ sudo mv -f ~/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver` and `USER@DESKTOP:~/Downloads$ sudo mv -f ~/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver` you are saying you want to move the file chromedriver from first location to other means replacing any files already in those locations with same name.
11. Last all i did was. close the vscode and relaunched it. and ran my code `node library.js` . and it worked it the chrome browser for me.

SOURCE CODE : LIBRARY.JS

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var By = webdriver.By;

var until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me is to use a local install of chromedriver. I got the error when I forgot to require chromedriver inside my script.

1. run `npm install`
2. in your node script have the line `require('chromedriver');` before you call a webdriver (I am using it with `selenium-webdriver`)

Not sure why it's not detecting your global path. If I don't have the line `require('chromedriver')` I can add the local chromedriver file to the path and it works.

Answer (score 0):

## been into a lot of confusion due to this for Jenkins windows slave

So here is how you can fix it

Following this link and download compatible driver as per your chrome version -

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/

Once driver is downloaded place it somewhere in c:\ drive like
c:\chromedriver

Add that path to your **System** environment variable - Reference is here https://www.browserstack.com/guide/run-selenium-tests-using-selenium-chromedriver

**Once that is done please note to ensure to reboot your windows machine else Jenkins won't be able to find it**

One more debug tip - I initially installed it using npm globally and added C:\Users\some_windows_user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules to system environment variable and rebooted my machine. That never worked in CI.

**So like I said above move it c:\chromedriver and add to System environment variable and 100% reboot you machine**

Answer (score 0):

Just puth this -

```
require("chromedriver");
```

before this -

```
let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
```