# Chrome browser does not start ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

I have:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Chrome version 58
- Node 6.10.1
- Npm 3.10.10
- chromedriver 2.29.0

Selenium standalone is run but after running my tests (with Chrome) there is an error in the console where selenium was run:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:181)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:41643/status] to be available after 20002 ms
```

In the console where I run my tests there is an error after running 27.0.0.1:4444 in the browser when selenium standalone is opened and the page is loaded:

> chrome
>   Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444

I tried with different versions node.js and npm but it did not help. I tried also with webdriver-manager instead of selenium-standalone server

when I change Firefox into Chrome FF browser is opened..

Earlier it worked with Chrome... but stopped. I do not know why (another person's work, and they have similar versions now).

Comment: DId you run selenium-standalone install? Sometimes it can be started without being properly "installed". Also make sure that Selenium is actually running when you run an individual test.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, updated my chromedriver version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a non-started Chrome driver. You need to do one of two things:

- ensure chromedriver.exe (latest version) is in one of the directories of your PATH
- set the location of this file in your code. I do it in Java, but I found the following question-answer regarding Javascript: [Passing require('chromedriver).path directly to selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733731/passing-requirechromedriver-path-directly-to-selenium-webdriver)

If you have done this and still have the error, please show the code that insiantiates and initializes the driver.

Comment: hi, wdio.conf file is here: pastebin com/Jd9WrH7B  I am running selenium server using  selenium-standalone start command